# Property 'glob' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'.ts

Tags: typescript, laravel, laravel-blade, vite

### Context

I am new to Vite and with very little experience in Laravel, I am trying to use Vite with Laravel for asset bundling.

I'm following instructions from Laravel official documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#blade-processing-static-assets

Since I'm using TypeScript, So my entry point file name is : `resources/ts/app.ts`

When I try to write

```
import.meta.glob([ 
  '../resources/img/..',
]);
```

I am able to get `Property 'glob' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'.ts(2339)`. I understand once files are build, I have to use
`<img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/logo.png') }}">`
to be able to see file, But since I'm skipping to update the `app.ts` file.

I am able to see `logo.png` as
`<imgsrc="https://sensitiveUrl.com/logo.a766f7e6.js"`

I am trying to bundle static assets ( images ), just like how I did with css/js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add **"types": ["vite/client"]** to *compilerOptions* in `tsconfig.json` in the project root directory.

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIBGi.png)

Also your vite.config.js file should configured correctly.

Comment: I also needed to add `"./node_modules"` to the typeRoots configuration for this to work

Comment: @ChristianC so am I

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vitepress with TypeScript and just fixed this issue by adding `"vite": "*"` to my `devDependencies`

Edit: I also added `"vue": "*"` in the end (other similar issues)

Comment: You are not supposed to use `"*"` for any dependency, ever. This means you will install the latest version, no matter what, even it's a major, breaking change. And if you go long enough, hunting down what version you do want will be tricky because you don't know what version worked.